# Tokenize with Regex Tokenizer

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenize the following sentence with regex tokenizer

```
MOST INTERESTED IN NUT BUTTERS
```

When I define my tokenizer as

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
```

I get output as

```
['MOST', 'INTERESTED', 'IN', 'NUT', 'BUTTERS']
```

My desired output is

```
['MOST', 'INTERESTED', 'IN', 'NUT BUTTERS']
```

I want NUT BUTTER to be a one element
I am not understanding what regular expression to use instead or \w+

Comment: `str = 'MOST INTERESTED IN NUT BUTTERS'` `str.split(' ', 3)`

Comment: This is just example stament.There is a document which has many more such statments and I want in all the staments that Nut Butter should remain same

Comment: What is the scheme behind `NUT BUTTERS` being treated differently?

Comment: I want to count the instances of    NUT BUTTERS in entire document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with a regex solution you will have to make a list of words that contain spaces that have to be extracted as one and build your regex like this:

```
word space1|word space2|word space3|...|word spaceN|\w+
```

for your example it becomes:

```
NUT BUTTERS|\w+
```

Comment: I just used nut butter as an example.Can I just place here the different words from a text file. For example if my text file has NUT BUTTERS MANGO APPLE.Then I would like to all of those in regex expression

Answer (score -1):

Try `split()` instead.

```
>>> str = 'MOST INTERESTED IN NUT BUTTERS'
>>> str.split(' ', 3) # 3 tells the number of splits it should do.
['MOST', 'INTERESTED', 'IN', 'NUT BUTTERS']
```